# How Can I Make the value of a date time picker value to null when loading a form?

Tags: c#, winforms

How Can I Make the value of a date time picker value to null when loading a form?
When I am using datetimepicker, it is displaying a default value when the form is loading. 
I have set both the minimum and maximum date for datetimepicker.

My Requirement is "to display null value(Nothing) in the datetimepicker so that user have to select date from the datetimepicker". I refereed so many sites. All those about Custom formats. I have my own idea. i,e Taking a button as Readonly and in the button click event, i can make the datetimepicker as visible. 
// in the datetimepicker_DateSelectd Event
   Button.text=datetimepicker.value;

But i dint satisfy with this.
Can u please suggest me.

Comment: I think your idea is pretty well and easy to do. Instead button you can use `TextBox`, e.g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do is

```
dtpConstDate.CustomFormat = " "; 
dtpConstDate.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
```

On value change you could do

```
private void dtp_ValueChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

  dtp.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short; 

}
```

So the idea is simple you could change the datetime picker format accordingly to achieve your goal.

Comment: Ya It's Working. But there is a small problem. I am setting Max date of dtp to Now.Date in the form load event. So immediately the dtp_Value changed is executing. Again the When Loading the form the date is displaying in dtp.

Comment: Can't get you, will you ellaborate?

Comment: Your idea is working. I did what u said. But in the form load i am setting max date property to dtp. So, the event"Value Changed" is handling here. So again the value of dtp can not be null when the form is loading, it is displaying some default value.

Comment: @Sushma Put these command below setting Max date.  `dtpConstDate.CustomFormat = " "; 
dtpConstDate.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;` It works

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the Text property?

```
dateTimePicker.Text = string.Empty;
```

or if in WPF:

```
<DateTimePicker Text="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as following ....

1 : Set Date Formate to be "CUSTOM"
   2 : Then CustomFormate = " " (Single Space)

When you did  that you will see your datetimepicker blank ........... but when you will run your program and try to select any date, you will not be able see your selected date ....... It will be still blank.

Solve it as following ............

Date1.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

Comment: In Design set Me.DateTimePicker1.CustomFormate= " 
"

Comment: Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged                                           
        'DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"'
    End Sub